# Android: AsyncTask - doesn't seem to run asynchroneously

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use AsyncTask to make a tas run apart from the main thread, thus prevent locking the thread while the task is running. Have I misunderstood the use for AsyncTask?

The calling code from the main thread:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int input = Integer.parseInt(editInput.getText().toString());
    String out = "";

    try {
        out = new RunAsyncTask().execute(Integer.toString(input)).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

From the AsyncTask class:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    long start, stop;
    long result;
    String out = "";
    int input = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

    // Dalvik (Java) - Recursive:
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = FibLib.fibJR(input);
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    out += String.format("Dalvik (Java) recursive: %d (%d msec)", result, stop - start);

    // Dalvik (Java) - Iterative:
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = FibLib.fibJI(input);
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    out += String.format("\nDalvik (Java) iterative: %d (%d msec)", result, stop - start);

    return out
```

From the FibLib class (which is called by the AsyncTask):

```
public class FibLib {
    public static long fibJR(long n) {  // 
        if (n <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return fibJR(n - 1) + fibJR(n - 2);
    }

    // Java implementation - iterative:
    public static long fibJI(long n) { // 
        long previous = -1;
        long result = 1;

        for (long i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            long sum = result + previous;
            previous = result;
            result = sum;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

However, when running this, the main GUI thread is still locked and crashes if the task is more than just a small, quick one. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: What does the stacktrace says? Maybe it crashes because of a `NumberFormatException`?.. I see you parse nunbers there..

Comment: Nah, only ints and no calculations other than addition. Shouldn't be a format problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the `AsyncTask`'s get() method, which really turns an asynchronous call to synchronous, because it waits for the result of the operation. A better way to return the result of the `AsyncTask` to the calling `Activity` is to use a callback interface. Create a simple `interface`, e.g.:

```
interface OnTaskCompletedListener {
    void onTaskCompleted(Object result);
}
```

Now implement that interface in your `Activity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTaskCompletedListener {}
```

Now you should pass the `MainActivity` to the `AsyncTask` object:

```
AsyncTask task = new RunAsyncTask(onTaskCompletedListener).execute();
```

And inside the `AsyncTask's onPostExecute()` you return the result to the listener:

```
onTaskCompletedListener.onTaskCompleted(result);
```

Now you can use the result in your `Activity`'s `onTaskCompleted()` method.

Hope the explanation was clear enough and it will help you.

Comment: Ah, that would explain a lot. Thanks. I'm not very familiar with creating interfaces, so it's about time I learned it :-)

Comment: @kakemonsteret, Glad the answer could help you! Please don't forget to accept the answer if you've found it useful.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as how to call/connect the onTaskCompletedListener? If I just do RunAsyncTask task = new RunAsyncTask(onTaskCompletedListener).execute(); in the main activity, I get "onTaskCompletedListener cannot be resolved to a variable"...

Comment: What I'm wondering is: 1. How to call AsyncTask from the main activity, with the onTaskCompletedListener? 2. How to write the constructor for RunAsyncTask so that it takes the onTaskCompletedListener as a parameter?

Comment: Never mind the last two comments - I was able to piece things together. Solution accepted as answer :-)